# How do i create a comment block in a hive script

Tags: hive

I am reworking a Hive script file. For debugging purposes I would like to set some blocks of code as comment. However I can't find a way to define such a comment block. Tried various options but none seem to work. Any hints?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive does not support multi-line comment.
Only single line comment are supported